# Ender 3 Y Layer Shifting

Tags: creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, layer-shifting

My school started a robotics club this year and one of the teachers gave us an Ender 3 printer to use, they assembled it the year before but never actually used it so it was sitting in their garage, I attempted to print several different objects but all of the larger ones seem to suffer from layer shifting on what seems like the Y axis. I've looked at other threads and tried stuff such as changing the binder clips (add adding more), leveling the bed (again), tightening the belts, moving the print position to a corner, using a different slicer, and reslicing the models which all fail, when I print smaller objects, it prints fine. What could the problem be and what can I do to resolve this? I'm using Cura 4.4 currently.

Failed print:

[image: failed print]

What it should look like:

[image: cad image]

Successful print (smaller object):

[image: successful print]

Edit: I'm also using OctoPrint on a Raspberry Pi for remote control but the issue still occurs when printing from an SD card.

Comment: Is the Y belt tight? What are your jerk and acceleration limits set in the slicer?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Yes, I tightened both the X and Y belt, print jerk is 20mm/s and acceleration is 500mm/s

I'm using the Magic0.20 profile from https://www.chepclub.com/cura-profiles.html (had the same issue with the default profile)

Comment: Do the cables of the bed get caught on something? Does the bed run smoothly without the belt? What is the print speed?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it finally, seems that the X axis was not level. Thank you to everyone who commented.

Comment: Do you have an understanding of how that caused the Y shifting? It would be interesting to hear more

Comment: The entire issue was on the x axis, it didn’t have anything to do with the y axis, the x axis was lower on the right side. My bad for confusing the x and y axis :)